# URI Scheme Redirect

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, windows-7, uri, google-chrome-frame

How can I create a special URI scheme to open a link in Internet Explorer from Google Chrome?

For example, if I execute `ie:google.com` in Chrome, a new window would open in IE with Google's homepage. I've followed the steps in "[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)", however it literally passes the string `ie:google.com` to IE, which IE has no idea what do with.

Essentially I need to remove the the `ie:` protocol once passed to IE, or setup some sort of protocol redirect to `http:` in the registry. Is either even possible?

Comment: I think I have a solution. I could create a [redirect in my internal app](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler) to strip out the "ie:" protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an internal app, I can just create a proxy in my internal app to strip out the "ie:" protocol. Registry looks like this...

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/
  ie/
    shell/
      open/
        command/
          (Default) "PathToExecutableIE" "ProxyLink?url=%1"
```

Then, my ProxyLink is a static VB.Net page that strips out the "ie:" part of the string, and redirects.